# How to determine whether an interface type implements a custom attibute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

How to determine whether an interface type implements a custom attibute?

Answer (score 5):

Use `GetCustomAttributes`:

```
typeof(IWhatever).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), false)
```

Will return an array of attributes.  Empty if it doesn't implement the one you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
private static bool HasAttribute(this Type me, Type attribute)
{
    if (!typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(attribute))
        throw new ArgumentException("attribute does not extend System.Attribute.");
    return me.GetCustomAttributes(attribute, true).Length > 0;
}
private static bool HasAttribute<T>(this Type me) where T : System.Attribute
{
    return me.HasAttribute(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: (null checks are for wusses!)

Answer (score -1):

```
Type iType = typeof(IMyInterface);
var attributes = iType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
```

If `attributes` is empty, then the Interface doesn't implement your attribute.